# Is it possible to use SELECT ST_GeomFromText( with other SELECT?

Tags: postgresql, geojson, sql, geometry

I'm trying to use SELECT ST_GeomFromText() with a value catched from another query:

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromText(
  ST_AsText(
    ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(
  SELECT 
    column-name
  FROM table-name
  ORDER BY id DESC
  LIMIT 1)
  ), 
4326);
```

The value that I'm trying to use is compatible with the `SELECT ST_GeomFromText()` and I'm using PostgreSQL/PostGIS.

Other solution that would help would be a `INSERT INTO` with `SELECT ST_GeomFromText()` as a value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54579810/is-it-possible-to-use-select-st-geomfromtext-with-other-select/54580328#54580328

Comment: Cross-posted as https://stackoverflow.com/q/54579810/820534

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromText(
         ST_AsText(
           CAST(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(t1."column-name") AS TEXT)
         ), 4326
       )
FROM (SELECT "column-name"
      FROM table-name
      ORDER BY id DESC
      LIMIT 1) AS t1
;
```

Comment: Hi, i tried your suggestion and the following error happened: 

ERROR:  function st_geomfromgeojson(json) does not exist
LINE 3:            ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(t1.geometria)
                   ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 56

Comment: In postgreSQL, what is the return type of the `geometria` field ? The entry data must be in `text`, `json` or `jsonb` type.

Comment: I'm using a JSON `{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-48.544464,-27.579818],[-48.548584,-27.60994],[-48.45005,-27.622717],[-48.439064,-27.584991],[-48.544464,-27.579818]]]}` and when i tried to use this json direct with the `SELECT ST_GeomFromText(
  ST_AsText(
    ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(`function it worked perfectly.

Comment: I think it's working now, I've cast the JSON as TEXT. I've corrected my post.

Comment: Same error:
`ERROR:  function st_geomfromgeojson(json) does not exist
LINE 3:            CAST(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(t1.geometria) AS TEXT)`

Comment: I changed the datatype of the column and then it worked. Thanks, it will help me a lot.